# XNA Compile Textures On The Fly

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm writing a program, and I need to convert a Texture2D object to a .xnb file. I've searched for an answer, but I can't find any. Is this possible? XNA 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these website as it explains it all here:

[MS Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx)

[MS Build Content Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.tasks.buildcontent.aspx)

This example shows how to use MS Build:

[XNA Winforms example](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)

Comment: Please note, the content pipeline assemblies are only installed with XNA Game Studio, and are not in the XNA redistributable ... so users of your app would have to have game studio installed. This may be ok, but you should be clear on that :-)

Comment: It says "The type or namespace name 'Pipeline' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" when I try to add a using statement.

Comment: @CommunistPancake: You need to add an assembly reference, to the appropriate assembly, to your project. You also need to change your project's build target from the .NET 4.0 Client Profile, to the full .NET 4.0 framework.